# Man page NAME (and the line under it) and DESCRIPTION (and lines under) in grep or

Tags: linux, bash, grep, command-line-interface, manpage

I am trying to condense a list of man pages for various tools to just:

```
NAME
    ls – list directory contents
DESCRIPTION
     For each operand that names a file of a type other than directory, ls displays its name as well as any requested, associated information.  For each operand that names a file of
     type directory, ls displays the names of files contained within that directory, as well as any requested, associated information.
```

The output should be the full NAME section and the full DESCRIPTION section. So when I type `man <tool name> | awk/grep/etc` it comes out like the code above.

I have tried to `man ls | grep "NAME"` and different variations of this. `man ls | col -bx | awk '/^[A-Z ]+$/ {print}'` which only gives me the Title name. And all sorts of combinations that lead me no where. Any suggestions?

Comment: Try `tldr` and `eg` github projects. https://github.com/tldr-pages

Comment: this is nice but I dont see a why to get just the two things I'm looking for

Comment: no, i dont see this being a solution, although I guess I can try print a man page to a text file then do a pattern search and discard the rest....

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the expected output. It's not clear if you want the whole DESCRIPTION or just the first paragraph or something else.

Comment: is it my title that isnt clear or the description so I know to be more detailed (apologies)

Comment: It's the expected output as I mentioned. You show 2 lines of DESCRIPTION for ls but on my system at least the DESCRIPTION for ls is about 50 lines. So are you truncating for the purposes of abbreviating your question or is that all you see on your system or do you only want 1 paragraph or 2 sentences or lines with a specific indent or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question isn't clear but maybe this is what you want as it looks like what you posted as expected output?

```
$ man ls | awk -v RS= '/^(NAME|DESCRIPTION)/'
NAME
       ls - list directory contents
DESCRIPTION
       List  information  about the FILEs (the current directory by default).  Sort entries alphabetically if none
       of -cftuvSUX nor --sort is specified.
```

but you say you want the full DESCRIPTION so then that'd be:

```
$ man ls | awk '
    /^[[:alnum:]]/{ prt(); rec="" }
    { rec = rec $0 ORS }
    END { prt() }
    function prt() {
        gsub(/^[[:space:]]+|[[:space:]]+$/,"",rec)
        if ( rec ~ /^(NAME|DESCRIPTION)/ ) {
            print rec
        }
    }
'
NAME
       ls - list directory contents
DESCRIPTION
       List  information  about the FILEs (the current directory by default).  Sort entries alphabetically if none
       of -cftuvSUX nor --sort is specified.

       Mandatory arguments to long options are mandatory for short options too.

       -a, --all
              do not ignore entries starting with .

       -A, --almost-all
              do not list implied . and ..

       --author
              with -l, print the author of each file

       -b, --escape
              print C-style escapes for nongraphic characters

       --block-size=SIZE
              with -l, scale sizes by SIZE when printing them; e.g., '--block-size=M'; see SIZE format below

       -B, --ignore-backups
              do not list implied entries ending with ~

       -c     with -lt: sort by, and show, ctime (time of last modification of file status information); with  -l:
              show ctime and sort by name; otherwise: sort by ctime, newest first

       -C     list entries by columns

       --color[=WHEN]
              colorize the output; WHEN can be 'always' (default if omitted), 'auto', or 'never'; more info below

       -d, --directory
              list directories themselves, not their contents

       -D, --dired
              generate output designed for Emacs' dired mode

       -f     list all entries in directory order

       -F, --classify[=WHEN]
              append  indicator  (one of */=>@|) to entries; WHEN can be 'always' (default if omitted), 'auto', or
              'never'

       --file-type
              likewise, except do not append '*'

       --format=WORD
              across -x, commas -m, horizontal -x, long -l, single-column -1, verbose -l, vertical -C

       --full-time
              like -l --time-style=full-iso

       -g     like -l, but do not list owner

       --group-directories-first
              group directories before files;

              can be augmented with a --sort option, but any use of --sort=none (-U) disables grouping

       -G, --no-group
              in a long listing, don't print group names

       -h, --human-readable
              with -l and -s, print sizes like 1K 234M 2G etc.

       --si   likewise, but use powers of 1000 not 1024

       -H, --dereference-command-line
              follow symbolic links listed on the command line

       --dereference-command-line-symlink-to-dir
              follow each command line symbolic link

              that points to a directory

       --hide=PATTERN
              do not list implied entries matching shell PATTERN (overridden by -a or -A)

       --hyperlink[=WHEN]
              hyperlink file names; WHEN can be 'always' (default if omitted), 'auto', or 'never'

       --indicator-style=WORD
              append  indicator  with  style  WORD  to  entry  names:  none  (default),  slash   (-p),   file-type
              (--file-type), classify (-F)

       -i, --inode
              print the index number of each file

       -I, --ignore=PATTERN
              do not list implied entries matching shell PATTERN

       -k, --kibibytes
              default to 1024-byte blocks for file system usage; used only with -s and per directory totals

       -l     use a long listing format

       -L, --dereference
              when showing file information for a symbolic link, show information for the file the link references
              rather than for the link itself

       -m     fill width with a comma separated list of entries

       -n, --numeric-uid-gid
              like -l, but list numeric user and group IDs

       -N, --literal
              print entry names without quoting

       -o     like -l, but do not list group information

       -p, --indicator-style=slash
              append / indicator to directories

       -q, --hide-control-chars
              print ? instead of nongraphic characters

       --show-control-chars
              show nongraphic characters as-is (the default, unless program is 'ls' and output is a terminal)

       -Q, --quote-name
              enclose entry names in double quotes

       --quoting-style=WORD
              use quoting style  WORD  for  entry  names:  literal,  locale,  shell,  shell-always,  shell-escape,
              shell-escape-always, c, escape (overrides QUOTING_STYLE environment variable)

       -r, --reverse
              reverse order while sorting

       -R, --recursive
              list subdirectories recursively

       -s, --size
              print the allocated size of each file, in blocks

       -S     sort by file size, largest first

       --sort=WORD
              sort by WORD instead of name: none (-U), size (-S), time (-t), version (-v), extension (-X), width

       --time=WORD
              change  the  default  of using modification times; access time (-u): atime, access, use; change time
              (-c): ctime, status; birth time: birth, creation;

              with -l, WORD determines which time to show; with --sort=time, sort by WORD (newest first)

       --time-style=TIME_STYLE
              time/date format with -l; see TIME_STYLE below

       -t     sort by time, newest first; see --time

       -T, --tabsize=COLS
              assume tab stops at each COLS instead of 8

       -u     with -lt: sort by, and show, access time; with -l: show access time and  sort  by  name;  otherwise:
              sort by access time, newest first

       -U     do not sort; list entries in directory order

       -v     natural sort of (version) numbers within text

       -w, --width=COLS
              set output width to COLS.  0 means no limit

       -x     list entries by lines instead of by columns

       -X     sort alphabetically by entry extension

       -Z, --context
              print any security context of each file

       --zero end each output line with NUL, not newline

       -1     list one file per line

       --append-exe
              append .exe if cygwin magic was needed

       --help display this help and exit

       --version
              output version information and exit

       The  SIZE  argument  is  an integer and optional unit (example: 10K is 10*1024).  Units are K,M,G,T,P,E,Z,Y
       (powers of 1024) or KB,MB,... (powers of 1000).  Binary prefixes can be used, too: KiB=K, MiB=M, and so on.

       The TIME_STYLE argument can be full-iso, long-iso, iso, locale, or +FORMAT.  FORMAT is interpreted like  in
       date(1).  If FORMAT is FORMAT1<newline>FORMAT2, then FORMAT1 applies to non-recent files and FORMAT2 to re‐
       cent files.  TIME_STYLE prefixed with 'posix-' takes effect  only  outside  the  POSIX  locale.   Also  the
       TIME_STYLE environment variable sets the default style to use.

       Using  color  to  distinguish  file  types  is  disabled  both  by  default  and  with --color=never.  With
       --color=auto, ls emits color codes only when standard output is connected to a terminal.  The LS_COLORS en‐
       vironment variable can change the settings.  Use the dircolors command to set it.

   Exit status:
       0      if OK,

       1      if minor problems (e.g., cannot access subdirectory),

       2      if serious trouble (e.g., cannot access command-line argument).
```

Comment: It was the first one I was looking for THANK YOU. That does work on linux, so I can just do it there...I wonder why it doesnt work on MacOS

Comment: The awk script will also work on MacOS so if you're not getting the expected output then maybe there's some control chars in among the text we're testing of the man page. Try `man ls | cat -v` to see any.

Comment: Since the first script is what you wanted you should fix your question to change `the full DESCRIPTION section` to `the first paragraph from the DESCRIPTION section` or similar.

Comment: @DontPanic : For MacOS (i.e. BSD Unix), have a look at `man man`, in particular what they say on the `-c` option.